# Paso por parametro clase vector

Tags: c++

Hola buenas el otro día intente hacer un programa que ordenara un vector de la clase Vector que se le pasaba por parámetro a una función. Pero me daba error de compilación, os dejo el código de la función:

```
void ordenar(vector<int>v){
  sort(v.begin(),v.end());
}
```

PD: he incluido tanto la librería vector como la librería algorithm.

Comment: Por favor, proporciona un [mcve] que reproduzca tu problema. Además, ¿ Qué error es el que obtienes ? Te sugiero consultar [¿ Cómo elaboro una buenta pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Comment: El código que muestras no da absolutamente ningún error de compilación si incluyes todas las librerías requeridas y usas la cláusula `using namespace std` en el lugar adecuado.

Comment: Ese código no va a funcionar, ya que le pasas una copia del vector. Tienes que pasar un `vector<int>&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es raro que te dé error de compilación, puede ser que alguna otra parte del código no esté funcionando correctamente, aún así, depende de como esté puesto el main, puede que no te haga la ordenación de forma correcta.
Supongo que si te da error es porqué en el main debes haber puesto algo parecido a esto

```
v = ordenar(v);
```

Y eso no está bien. De hecho te recomiendo que el parámetro de la función lo pases por referencia de esta manera:

```
void ordenar(vector<int>&v){
  sort(v.begin(),v.end());
}
```

El ampersand, lo que hace es directamente modificar el parámetro de la función. Cuando tu creas una función en c++, las puedes crear por referencia o por valor. En las funciones por valor, copias el contenido del parámetro en un nuevo espacio de memoria, y en las funciones por referencia, se modifica directamente el parámetro.
Por tanto el código quedaría algo así, implementando un main de ejemplo:

```
void ordenar(vector<int>&v){
  sort(v.begin(),v.end());
}
int main(){
    vector<int> v(5);
    v = {4,3,1,5,2};
    ordenar(v);
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado :D